# Spotfire how to make calculation along one coloumn

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a data table as below.I would like to create a new column called "Time Difference" which captures the time difference between [STAGE] start and [STAGE] end. Is there any way to do it without using data transformation?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can each ID only have 1 start and 1 end?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each `ID` is unique, and your data is ordered by `Time` where `Stage = Start` is the first row for each `ID` and `Stage = End` is the last row for each `ID`, you can use this:

```
Concatenate(Min([Time]) OVER ([ID]),"-",Max([Time]) over ([ID]))
```

**RESULTS**

```
+----+---------+---------+------+-----------------+
| ID |  Stage  | Action  | Time | Time Difference |
+----+---------+---------+------+-----------------+
|  1 | Start   | approve | A    | A-F             |
|  1 | Process | approve | B    | A-F             |
|  1 | Process | approve | C    | A-F             |
|  1 | Process | approve | D    | A-F             |
|  1 | Process | decline | E    | A-F             |
|  1 | End     | approve | F    | A-F             |
|  2 | Start   | approve | G    | G-I             |
|  2 | Process | decline | H    | G-I             |
|  2 | End     | approve | I    | G-I             |
+----+---------+---------+------+-----------------+
```

If your data isn't already sorted, you can just apply a `Rank()` to fix this. Let me know if that's the case.

> **EDIT WITH NEW DATA**

**EXPRESSION**

```
Concatenate(Min(If((Upper([Stage])="START") and (Upper([Action])="APPROVE"),Max([Time]) OVER ([ID]))) OVER ([ID]),"-",Min(If((Upper([Stage])="END") and (Upper([Action])="APPROVE"),Max([Time]) OVER ([ID]))) OVER ([ID]))
```

**Simplified**

```
Concatenate(Min(If((Upper([Stage])="START") and (Upper([Action])="APPROVE"),[Time])) OVER ([ID]),"-",Min(If((Upper([Stage])="END") and (Upper([Action])="APPROVE"),[Time])) OVER ([ID]))
```

**RESULTS**

```
+----+---------+---------+------+-----------------+
| ID |  Stage  | Action  | Time | Time Difference |
+----+---------+---------+------+-----------------+
|  1 | On hold | decline | A    | C-H             |
|  1 | Start   | decline | B    | C-H             |
|  1 | Start   | approve | C    | C-H             |
|  1 | Process | DECLINE | D    | C-H             |
|  1 | Process | approve | E    | C-H             |
|  1 | Process | approve | F    | C-H             |
|  1 | End     | decline | G    | C-H             |
|  1 | End     | approve | H    | C-H             |
|  2 | Start   | approve | I    | I-K             |
|  2 | Process | decline | J    | I-K             |
|  2 | End     | approve | K    | I-K             |
+----+---------+---------+------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Hi i think i did not state my question clearly. sometimes the first stage of each [ID] is not "start" and the last stage is not "end", so the condition has to be make specifically that i want to get the start time when [stage] equals to start,[action]equals to approve and the end time when [stage]equals to end and [action]equals to approve. thanks!

Comment: @BenWang can you provide another sample dataset which takes this into consideration?

Comment: and also the G-I means the time difference between those two time spot

Comment: @BenWang I'm unsure what you mean by your last comment, but I provided another solution.

Comment: do you mind explaining it a bit? why do we need max([Time]) over [ID] and why do we need a min([Time]) over id? thanks

Comment: `OVER()` expressions can only be used with aggregation methods. 
The syntax for `OVER()` is `<method>(<method arguments>) over (<over methods>)`. `MIN()` and `MAX()` are arbitrary here. `FIRST()`, `LAST()`, and other methods could have similar results. `OVER()` was needed to identify the **GROUP** of rows to apply the logic which your question required, which is to group the data based off `[ID]`

Comment: understood. but to be more specific, why do i need max(time)over id nested by min(time) over id?

Comment: I guess for this specific case, you don't and it could be simplified to `Concatenate(Min(If((Upper([Stage])="START") and (Upper([Action])="APPROVE"),[Time])) OVER ([ID]),"-",Min(If((Upper([Stage])="END") and (Upper([Action])="APPROVE"),[Time])) OVER ([ID]))`

Comment: make sense! and i think the reason we add max() or min before over is just spotfire needs a aggregation before over right? i tried change min to max the result is still the same.

Comment: Correct, and changing it won't matter here. You could use First or Last... that's because we are looking at the `Stage` and `Action`. But... if you had two rows where `ID = 1` and `Stage = Start` and `Action = Approve` and set the `Time` to different values... the `MIN` and `MAX` would show different results. We are limiting it to **one** row so the aggregate doesn't matter, yet is required for the method.

Comment: No problem @BenWang glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer when possible! Cheers Mate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138949/discussion-between-ben-wang-and-scsimon).

Comment: please consider accepting this answer if you feel it was correct @BenWang

Comment: sorry, i thought i have already accepted it by click the up button, do you know what else should i do?

Comment: sorry i completely forgot to click the correct button, my apology, just did it

Comment: Hey man ain't no problem at all, we all forget things and i'm the world's worst haha